# Injective operator systems

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

An operator system $\mathcal{S} \subseteq B(\mathcal{H})$ is called **injective** if given an operator system inclusion $\mathcal{M} \subseteq \mathcal{N} \subseteq B(\mathcal{K})$ each completely positive map $\phi : \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ has a completely positive extension $\phi : \mathcal{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{S}$.

Arveson has shown that $B(\mathcal{H})$ is injective, hence every $C^*-$ algebra is an injective operator system and in particular finite dimension matrices are injective.
I'd like to know if there is some method or result to check if a more general operator system is injective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, injectivity does not pass to subspaces. This is a tricky subject. A few facts:

- There is no characterization of injective C$^*$-algebras.
- Finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebras are injective.
- Injective C$^*$-algebras are monotone-complete, which implies that no separable infinite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra is injective (properly: an infinite-dimensional injective C$^*$-algebra is non-separable). So all the usual C$^*$-algebras (UHF, Cuntz, reduced C$^*$-algebras of countable groups, $K(H)$, Jiang-Su, etc., etc., etc.) are not injective.
- Injective von Neumann algebras are well-understood. This was Connes monumental Annals paper from 1976. In summary, a von Neumann algebra is injective if and only if it is AFD.
- Via the Choi-Effros product, it can be shown that an injective operator system is completely order isomorphic to a C$^*$-algebra.
- Hamana proved in 1979 that every operator system has an *injective envelope*, that is a smallest injective operator system that contains the given one.
- In light of all the above, a characterization of injective operator systems is hopeless. As far as I can tell (I haven't thought about this stuff for a while), there is not even any characterization of when a finite-dimensional operator system is injective. The answer is easy for $2$-dimensional operator systems as they are all isomorphic to $\mathbb C^2$ and thus injective. But I don't think there's a way to tell when a 3-dimensional operator system is injective.

Comment: Got it... I was dealing with a e general operator system on my thesis and I hoped to use the product  defined in Choi effros proof using the projector.. but of course I don’t have injectivity in hypotheses..

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, it might be enough to work in the injective envelope, and there you can use the Choi-Effros product. But it is definitely not true that every operator system is isomorphic to a C$^*$-algebra.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Nice answer! You say: "An infinite-dimensional injective $C^*$-algebra is not separable". Do you know a reference for this? Thanks!

Comment: I'll try to write an ad-hoc argument later. But basically, an injective C$^*$-algebra $A$ is monotone-complete. It follows that every masa in $A$ is monotone complete. This shows that $A$ is an AW$^*$ algebra, and these are generated by projections. Then one can use the same argument that is used to show that infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebras are non-separable: produce a countable family of pairwise orthogonal projections and use it to embed $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ into it.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks, makes sense!

Comment: Would you like to give me some reference for the fact that injective $C^*$
-algebras are monotone-complete?

Comment: It's basically what I mentioned in the comment above. I'll try to write it down with more detail.